# Angular Universal how to set NODE_ENV to production

Tags: angular, express, angular-universal

I have Angular 13 with Universal Express server, but can't figure out how to set Express NODE_ENV to production.

When I `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);` always get **"development"**

I try to add NODE_ENV=production in my package.json commands but had no success at all.

Have anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just update you package script:

```json
"start:prod": "export NODE_ENV=production || set NODE_ENV=production&&node ./dist",
```

Note, that `export NODE_ENV=production` is for iOS/Linux and `set NODE_ENV=production` (without a   [space] behind) is for windows.